# Pass a class to a jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to create a function and re use it by passing a class to the trigger / click? I have a block of code click event and I would rather reuse the block of code based on a class rather than rewrite numerous blocks of code for each instance. the classes are .playlist-one, .playlist-two, .playlist-three

Jquery:

```
$('.playlist-one').on('click', function () {
        var videoIndex = $('.playlist-one').index(this),
          targetThumbnail = $(this).closest('.video-playlist').find('.video-thumbnail').eq(videoIndex),
      });
```

Comment: create a generic function with arrays and pass that array in

Comment: Give all of your elements a common class, like "playlist", then you won't need to differentiate like that.

Comment: Also, what are you expecting `$('.playlist-one').index(this)` to do? `this` is a reference to `.playlist-one` so you're looking for an index of an element within itself which doesn't seem to make any sense. Also, end your statements with `;` not `,`